# Laravel route doesn't get to the controller

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

My project was working just fine till few hours ago. Some routes still working and some stopped. I tried to delete the new modification I made but the problem persists!!!!!
For example, this route used to go to index() method at the guest controller and returns a gust view of activities, and still working fine:

```
Route::get('activities', 'guestController@showguestactivities');
```

and this line of code used to go to index() method at the activities controller, but for now it returns just whit-blank page:

```
Route::resource('admin/activities', 'activitiesController');
```

I tried to return just a string like that:

```
Route::get('admin/activities', function(){return 'Just string for Activiteis';});
```

but it returns the white page again.
I found that there is a conflict happening with this resource:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'adminController');
```

once I remove it, every thing else works. But I need this resource and I can't just delete it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `artisan clear-compiled` and `artisan optimize`.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk still shows blank page. :(

Comment: Can you show us the `index` method of your `activitiesController`?

Comment: It doesn't go to the index at all, I'm sure of that.

Comment: Please, check the question as I edited it again with some thing I found last few minutes. @lukasgeiter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the order is of importance. If you register `admin/activities` before `admin` it should work fine:

```
Route::resource('admin/activities', 'activitiesController');
Route::resource('admin', 'adminController');
```

Comment: Alright alright you're welcome :) But please delete the [new question you created](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27730869/1903366)!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
Route::get('admin/activities', 'activitiesController@index');
```

instead of

```
Route::resource('admin/activities', 'activitiesController');
```

Comment: yes,of course, it works fine. but I need to access the whole controller (edit, update, store....etc) in a normal way .